# Stopping network calls without stopping javascript execution

Tags: javascript, intern

#### Context

We're running some functional unit tests using [theintern.io](http://theintern.io). Unfortunately, third party network calls randomly cause the page to time out, thus causing *all* of our unit tests to fail.

At a certain point, I'd like to cut the cord on all network calls to prevent the browser from hanging / tests from failing. I've tried `window.stop()`, but this causes the test to hang.

#### Question

How can I stop all network calls *without* also stopping javascript execution of my functional tests?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `window.stop` won't stop javascript execution, in your case it might look like its doing so, if the tests are getting loaded dynamically. 
`window.stop` is same as click stop button on your browser's address bar (Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/stop).

Now coming to your questions, there are multiple ways to handle this, my suggestion would be to mock all the network calls. (Assuming the third party calls that you mentioned are all AJAX). This is also a good practice while writing unit tests. You can use `sinon` for this. (Source: http://sinonjs.org/)

You can give an expected response, or just give a `404` or anything else, and respond immediately to the requests. That way, your tests won't timeout. Hope it helps

```
{
  beforeEach() {
    server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
  },
  afterEach() {
   server.restore()
  },
  tests: {
    testA() {
        server.respondWith("GET", /<regexPattern>/,[200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"},""]);
        server.respondImmediately = true;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Or you can just stub out the window.XMLHttpRequest object